# Прозрачное чтение-запись структур данных из/в файл (а). Python

Tags: python, файлы, структуры

**Доброго времени суток!**

Работаю с `Python3`, `Windows`

Возникла следующая ситуация: требуется записывать данные в виде списков и словарей в файл, а за тем в неизменном виде считывать их обратно.

Конечно, возможно заморочиться и писать парсинг строк с помощью модуля `re`, но такой метод выходит не универсальным.

Собственно вопрос: имеется ли стандартные модули/методы для реализации данной задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте стандартный модуль pickle. Он позволяет легко записывать в файл и обратно загружать из файла большинство стандартных объектов python.

Пример работы модуля:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> data = {
...     'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
...     'b': ("character string", b"byte string"),
...     'c': {None, True, False}
... }
>>>

    # Сохраняем словарь data в файл data.pickle

>>> with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
...     pickle.dump(data, f)
...

    # Читаем содержимое файла data.pickle в переменную data_new

>>> with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
...     data_new = pickle.load(f)
...

    # Убеждаемся, что в переменной data_new лежит словарь,
    # идентичный первоначальному

>>> print(data_new)
{'c': {False, True, None}, 'a': [1, 2.0, 3, (4+6j)], 'b': ('character string', b'byte string')}

    # Profit!
```

Подробнее про pickle можно почитать, например, здесь:
https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-pickle.html